# pandoc full-featured online?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

Is pandoc hosted anywhere for online use with complete functionality? The [online pandoc demo](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/) lacks PDF output and has a character limit.

Specifically, I'd to convert Markdown to PDF with embedded LaTeX, which offline pandoc does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've wrapped Pandoc in a web service. You can try it here https://github.com/mrded/pandoc-as-a-service 
Usage:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/markdown" -X POST -d "# hello" http://localhost/html
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, on [Authorea](https://authorea.com) you can write Markdown, LaTeX (as well as rich text) and convert your content to PDF, Word, or LaTeX. The conversion is performed via an underlying Pandoc process.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with the workflow `pandoc<->latex->PDF`, an alternative is [sharelatex](http://sharelatex.com). It's [open source](https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex) and can be self-hosted.

Comment: "Overleaf and ShareLaTeX have joined forces to bring you Overleaf v2", So it's now called Overleaf

Answer (score 0):

[Docverter](http://www.docverter.com/) is basically Pandoc as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on [SageMathCloud](http://cloud.sagemath.com).
The downside is that you have to create an account to use it.
Once logged in, create a project or open the project in which you want to work.
Create your markdown file `file.md`. Fill it up with text. Open a terminal and write your pandoc incantation, for example

```
    pandoc file.md -o file.pdf
```

Push <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then go back to fileview and you'll view your converted pdf there.